# Excel Customer List

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have Excel workbook with 2 sheets, a form sheet and a customer data sheet. The customer data sheet has an ID in column A (ex. F669) with the customer's full name in column B. Is there away I can get a list of all customer names that have the same ID to show up on my form sheet based on the ID that I enter on that form?

Thanks,

I've tried using a Unique function, but didn't work. I tried the following formula, but it only shows two of the customers that has the ID that I entered.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(ContactRecs!B:B,SMALL(IF(ContactRecs!$A:$A=FormHome!$S$45,ROW(ContactRecs!$B:$B)),ROW(7:7))*1,1),"")
```

I'm not sure what else to try.

Thanks,

Comment: Without looking at exactly what it is you tried, just by reading the 1st paragraph of your question it feels like you need `FILTER()`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the FILTER formula:

`=UNIQUE(FILTER(ContactRecs!B:B,ContactRecs!A:A=FormHome!$S$45))`

It filters column B on ContactRecs based on the ID given on your FormHome-Sheet.
As you already tried UNIQUE I added it to the filter result.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not quite sure how to attach the file to this question.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: sorry, I thought you would like to see the file. My bad. I tried using the Unique Filter formula, but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you have Excel 365? Otherwise unique and Filter won't work - that's right